# How do I for-each over a Knockout.JS observableArray?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

All attempts to iterate over a KO observableArray have failed. The flow just jumps over the block like the array is empty.

It's not, because its bound to some HTML and the debugger shows 7 items.

I've tried a normal `for` with an indexer, an ECMA-5+ `forEach` and now KO's own `arrayForEach` utility.

```
var EditorViewModel = function (firstDayOfWeek) {

    this.firstDayOfWeek = firstDayOfWeek;
    this.days = ko.observableArray([]); // Added in server-side generated view below.

    // Reads the activity data from each day and constructs and uploads models.
    this.save = function () {

        var basket = [];

        // Construct the upload activity models.

        ko.utils.arrayForEach(this.days(), function(d) {

            ... // never falls into this block.
```

There's nothing much out on the web about this, so I guess its a no-brainer. I'm obviously messing it up somehow, but its eluding me this afternoon.

`this.days` array looks good to me.

[image: Dump of debugger showing 7 items in array]

Thanks, Luke

Comment: Reproduce the problem. Set up a fiddle. Everything else is guesswork.

Answer (score 6):

here **days** is a **observableArray** which is nothing but a function , to iterate you need to read the value like days() , this is will give you a javascript array.

```js
var days = ko.observableArray([1,3,4,5,6]);

days().forEach(function(v,i){
  alert(v);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your answer. I am aware of that, but it makes no difference. It's just acting like its empty, but I can output the contents with `this.days()` in the console just fine. Very odd.

Comment: @LukePuplett than what you want to achieve, can you explain little more.?

Comment: Well, why is it acting like its empty when it isn't? It's proving more of a fist-clencher than a head-scratcher.

Comment: for me it is working like what it is, when there is not item in array it is not going to loop and when there are value in array it is going to loop , thats it should react.

Comment: Yep, okay, and my problem is that it is not looping despite there being items in the array. See above.

Comment: Yeah, Luke, it should be working since you're doing things correctly. Especially since the debugger is showing this.days() in the foreach to be non empty. Not that this is correct, but can you set a new var right before the foreach loop, var arr = this.days();, and do the foreach on that arr instead? I wonder if the observable object behaves weird with this iterative function.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why its not working with the `forEach` methods, but I did get it going with a properly written traditional `for` index iterator.

```
for (dayIndex = 0; dayIndex < this.days().length; dayIndex++) { ... }
```

Comment: utility function `arrayForEach` should work . you find any errors in console mate . can you show us what you got at  `function(d)`  . cheers

Comment: There were no errors in the console. There was nothing wrong as far as I could tell, no 'compilation' errors reported by Chrome. It should have worked. I should have filmed it. I'm sure it'll come up again later and I can see what the deal is, I've now moved on.